# multiple repositories throwing a 404 trying to update on 15.04

Tags: apt, updates, update-manager, ppa, launchpad

I have 15.05 installed on my desktop, i recently installed it on my laptop and it was working fine, i opened it today and attempted to do an apt-get update and i'm having multiple repositories  in the launchpad.net vivid/main return 404 errors, i've been Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found online for awhile now and i haven't found anything that works so far, can anyone out there point me in the right direction. here is a full list of the outputted repo's that aren't working.

```
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main amd64 Packages                                                                                    
404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages                                                                                     
404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en_US                                                                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en                                                                                    
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main amd64 Packages                                                                                    
404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main i386 Packages                                                                                     
404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en_US                                                                                 
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net vivid/main Translation-en                                                                                    
Fetched 1,960 B in 15s (124 B/s)                                                                                                          
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/freyja-dev/unity-tweak-tool-daily/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems that these PPAs don't have packages for 15.04 vivid yet.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/pidgin/+bug/1454598

> The launchpad repos give a 404 for Pidgin since my dist-upgrade to 15.04:
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/source/Sources 404 Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-amd64/Packages 404 Not Found
>
> W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pidgin-developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/vivid/main/binary-i386/Packages 404 Not Found